# Custom form action in Vue

Tags: forms, laravel, vue.js

i am using form in Vuejs component template. i don't want to define full static URL. the page URL is like http://example.com/en/discusses
and form should submit at http://example.com/comments.
but using

```
<form action = "comments" method ="POST">
```

goes to http://example.com/en/comments instead of http://example.com/comments. How to achieve this?. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `action="/comments"`

Comment: already tried  but not working.

Comment: Is your route grouped under any prefix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give your post route a name in the routes file (routes/web.php):

For example:

```
Route::post('/comments', 'SomeController@store')->name('postComment');
```

Normally then, you can use the named route in your form in the blade view:

```
<form action="{{ route('postComment') }}" method="POST">
</form>
```

In this case you use a Vue component, you can pass the 'postComment' route

```
<component post-route="{{ route('postComment') }}"></component>
```

Then, accept the property in your Vue component file:

```
<template>
 <form action="this.post-route" method="POST"></form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 props: ['post-route']
}
</script>
```

Comment: I used `:post-route="{{ json_encode(route('login')) }}"` in blade.php and works now!

Answer (score 0):

for ajax calls I'm using axios it has axios.default.baseUrl = 'yourBaseUrl'

yourBaseUrl is added before every ajax call You do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Vue and the above answer is exactly what I'm trying to do! I'm just not sure in which file you have used the Vue component to pass the "postComment" route:

```
<component post-route="{{ route('postComment') }}"></component>
```

Would it have its own file with passing the route as props being its only purpose? I think I am missing something..!

Thankyou!

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33457727)